# Using mmap to load huge file in the main memory by chunking

Tags: python, memory-management, mmap

I'm trying to load huge file through mmap, however the size of the file is huge and it does take around 13 minutes to be loaded, I thought to myself that I should chunk the file to number of cores that I have in my machine. And each core will have its own process to load a chunk of data into main memory.

Now the problem is how can I do that? . The file that I'm trying to load is written in binary.

I used python mmap. 
I have set the length of the file to be : size of file / number of cores
I tried to used offset but I can't shift it to the chunk size I can also offset it to the page size which causes other problems.

Comment: Can you provide code for what you have done? Maybe I can improve on it.

Comment: Mmap should be fast regardless of the size of the file unless MMAP_POPULATE or MAP_LOCKED is used. Unless the file is compressed or encrypted, loading will be IO bound and using more CPUs will not help.

Comment: sorry i did not notice your comments, i have a file that is 100 GB written in binaries, and it is not organized. meaning: the file has a header in the first 300 bytes, then information to that header, then the process is repeated . a small example is like this : 300b header 5123b data, another 300b header 5234b data. i